# React basics, encountering "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when creating a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following the FullStack Open course and we're just going over react basics.

However, the following basic code is used as an example of props, and whenever I put the code in my IDE or the chrome console it freaks out.

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { counter } = props
  return (
    <div>{counter}</div>
  )
}

let counter = 1

const refresh = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App counter={counter} />, 
  document.getElementById('root'))
}

refresh()
counter += 1
refresh()
counter += 1
refresh()
```

It's freaking out because of the "<" character creating the div container. This seems like really basic stuff, and I know the code is right compared to the website, so I'm a little unclear as to the problem. Here is the lesson for reference:

https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/component_state_event_handlers

Comment: Your code is probably fine--the issue is most likely an environment problem. How are you running the code? This needs to be transpiled by something like Babel to be compatible with a console, so your build setup is important. If you're just getting started, best to work in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/topic/react/templates) using a template.

Comment: Yes, the `<` is from the [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) of the React component and that requires a transpilation step. If you're pasting your code in the [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl) you'll see what Javascript code will be generated by Babel. That code can run in a Chrome console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an environment issue. You need to use tools like Babel to transpile your code. I would recommend checkout out Webpack and setting up a config file for development purposes. There will be many ‘boilerplate’ Webpack config set ups on Github that you could use, to save time setting it up yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks, I created a project with the create-react-app function which I believe includes a Webpack with a transpiler, but something must have gone wrong, or maybe it doesn't include a transpiler. Either way, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.